# A way to simplify $\gcd(a,b)$ condition in a double sum?

Tags: number-theory

I have

$$\sum_{{\Large 1 \leq a,b \leq L} \atop {\Large  \gcd(a,b)=1}}(L+1-a)(L+1-b)$$

Which means iterating $1 \le a \le L$ and $1 \le b \le L$ and only adding $(L+1-a)(L+1-b)$ to the sum if $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Is there a faster way that is not $O(N^2)$? I know how to count how many coprime pairs there are under a limit but not how to take into account the $a$ and $b$ and how they contribute to the sum

Comment: Feels like I have this before? A Deja-vû? Ahhh, they've change the Matrix...

Comment: Have noticed the `edit` option below the question? No need to delete a question...and I guess there are plenty of people around here that known Möbius things quite well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could simplify as follows:
\begin{align}
\sum_{{\Large 1 \leq a,b \leq L} \atop {\Large  \gcd(a,b)=1}}{(L+1-a)(L+1-b)}& =L^2+2 \cdot \left(\sum_{{\Large 1 \leq b<a \leq L} \atop {\Large  \gcd(a,b)=1}}{(L+1-a)(L+1-b)}\right) \\
& =L^2+2 \cdot \left(\sum_{\Large 2 \leq a \leq L}{(L+1-a)\sum_{{\Large 1 \leq b<a} \atop {\Large  \gcd(a,b)=1}}{(L+1-b)}}\right) \\
& =L^2+2 \cdot \left(\sum_{\Large 2 \leq a \leq L}{(L+1-a)\left((L+1)\varphi{(a)}-\frac{a\varphi{(a)}}{2}\right)}\right) \\
& =L^2+2\cdot \left(\sum_{\Large 2 \leq a \leq L}{(L+1-a)\left(L+1-\frac{a}{2}\right)\varphi{(a)}} \right)
\end{align}

Now you just need to sum over $a$. Is that fast enough for you?

**Edit:** One simple way to compute $\varphi{(a)}$ for $2 \leq a \leq L$ would be to recursively generate the [Farey sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) $F_n$ up to $n=L$, and take difference of number of terms of successive sequences along the way: $|F_a|-|F_{a-1}|=\varphi{(a)}$

Comment: There still the question of the time to compute $\phi(a)$. Not sure how much time it takes to compute $\phi(a)$ for $a=1\dots L$.

Comment: Hmm yes that might be a problem. We can compute $\varphi{(a)}, 1 \leq a \leq L$ by generating the Farey sequence recursively up to $L$, then taking differences. There are simple algorithms for this. I'm not sure about what running time is needed for generating Farey series though.

Comment: The Farey sequence up to $L$ contains $O(L^2)$ elements, though, so that's not really efficient.

Comment: @IvanLoh Where does L^2+2 come from

Comment: $a=b=1$ gives $L^2$. All other terms have $a \not =b$, but since it is symmetrical, we may just count for $a>b$, then multiply by $2$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews yes I suppose it isn't that efficient either, but I don't think the sum can be simplified further. It is definitely faster than simply calculating $\gcd$ of each pair and adding to the sum accordingly though (which isn't exactly $O(L^2)$, as you need to factor in the running time to compute $\gcd$, which should be around $O(\ln{L})$)

Comment: @IvanLoh And how do you transform the (L+1-b) to that phi(n) expression in the third step? Where did b go?

Comment: Well there are $\varphi{(a)}$ terms in the sum so $L+1$ becomes $(L+1)\varphi{(a)}$. Also, $\sum\limits_{{\Large 1 \leq b<a} \atop {\Large  \gcd(a,b)=1}}{b}=\frac{a\varphi{(a)}}{2}$. To see why, note that if $b$ is relatively prime to $a$, so is $a-b$. Now multiply the sum by $2$, and group $b$ and $a-b$.

Comment: Computing an individual god might take log time, but you can compute all the logs of pairs recursively by using $(a,b)=(a-b,b)$ when $a>b$